# Quantidade de repetições por caractere

Tags: javascript

Um amigo me passou o seguinte exercício:

> Crie uma função frequenciaLetra(text) que retorne um objeto contendo a quantidade de ocorrências de cada caracter presente no texto.

Eu parti do pressuposto que o argumento passado é uma string. De acordo com minha lógica eu criei duas estruturas de `for` sendo que a mais interna possui um `if` para verificar se existe a letra no texto passado. Porém ao terminar o `for` mais interno ele não retorna para o externo, e encerra a lógica na primeira iteração.

Segue o código para que vocês vejam o que estou fazendo:

```
function letterFrequence(text) {
    var repeticao;
    var listaComRepeticoes = [];
    var text = text.split("");

    for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
        repeticao = 0 ;
        var caractere = text[i];
        console.log("test");
        listaComRepeticoes.push(caractere);

        for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
            console.log("teste2");
            if (caractere === text[i]) {
                repeticao = repeticao + 1;
            } else {

            }
        };
        listaComRepeticoes.push(repeticao);
    };
    return listaComRepeticoes ;
}

var repeticoes =  letterFrequence("David Bastos");
console.log(repeticoes);
```

Saída do Console:

```
test
teste2
teste2
teste2
teste2
teste2
teste2
teste2
teste2
teste2
teste2
teste2
teste2
[ 'D', 1 ]
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

Percebam que o `for` mais interno roda as 12 interações do `text.lenght`, porém o mais externo não! O que eu poderia estar fazendo de errado?

Comment: Veja uma [solução alternativa](http://jsfiddle.net/zxqvctqe/) baseada no [count_chars()](http://www.php.net/count_chars) do PHP criada pelo pessoal da [PHP.JS](http://phpjs.org/functions/count_chars/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A [resposta do carlosfigueira](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/31966/74) resolve o problema, mas tem uma maneira mais fácil de fazer a contagem: em vez da array, usar um objeto como dicionário, com cada caractere como chave e a quantidade correspondente como valor. Por exemplo:

```
function letterFrequence(text) {
    var frequencias = {}
    for(var i=0; i<text.length; i++) {
        // se já temos esse caractere no dicionário, 
        // incrementa a quantidade  
        if(frequencias[text[i]]) {
            frequencias[text[i]]++;   

        // se ainda não temos, inicializa como 1
        } else {
            frequencias[text[i]] = 1;
        }
    }
    return frequencias;
}
```

<sup>http://jsfiddle.net/hqot1fke/</sup>

Exemplo de saída para `letterFrequence("David Bastos")`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Nota: implementações mais antigas de JavaScript não aceitam pegar caracteres de uma string usando *subscript* (ou seja, colchetes). Para maior compatibilidade, é melhor usar `text.charAt(i)` em vez de `text[i]`.

Comment: Que é basicamente o que o pessoal da PHP.JS fez XD

Comment: A versão deles é um pouco mais complexa, e a saída é em outro formato. Prefiro a simplicidade...

Comment: É que eles insistem em portar o PHP pro JS tanto quanto possível, daí tem de seguir ao pé da letra, com todos os modos disponíveis e etc. Eu acho besteira. Acho que nunca usei essa função nem mesmo no PHP. :p

Answer (score 5):

Em sua função você "declarou" a variável `i` duas vezes: uma no `for` externo, e uma no `for` interno. No entanto, para JavaScript, a variável está declarada apenas uma vez. O que acontece é que no final do laço interno a variável `i` terá o valor de `text.length`, o que satisfaz a condição de parada do laço externo.

Note que esse é um comportamento típico de JavaScript (escopo da variável ligada à função); em outras linguagens (C, C++, C#, Java IIRC, etc.) o escopo da variável é ligado ao *bloco* em que ela foi declarada.

Se você passar a usar uma outra variável no laço interno (como no exemplo abaixo) você irá ver o laço externo sendo executado múltiplas vezes.

```
    for (var j = 0; j < text.length; j++) {
        console.log("teste2");
        if (caractere === text[j]) {
            repeticao = repeticao + 1;
        } else {
        }
    };
```