# Reduzir array pela chave/valor em javavascript

Tags: javascript, array

Como eu posso reduzir o array agrupando-o pela chave/valor sendo que as chaves que recebo são dinâmicas?

*Input:*

```
[
    {
        "CORAS": "PP007"
    },
    {
        "CORAS": "PP008"
    },
    {
        "COREN": "PP007"
    },
    {
        "COREN": "PP008"
    },
    {
        "COREN": "PP002"
    },
    {
        "COREN": "VNL020"
    },
    {
        "COREN": "VNL121"
    }
]
```

*Output:*

```
{
    "CORAS": ["PP007", "PP008"],
    "COREN": ["PP007", "PP008", "PP002", "VNL020", "VNL121"]
}
```

Comment: O que você já tentou? Veja as respostas [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/31962/74), a solução é muito similar.

Comment: Já tentou algo Tiago?

Comment: Sendo o mais sincero, não entendi qual função posso utilizar pra realizar esse map

Comment: Precisaríamos ver como fez para ajudar, edita a pergunta com o que já tentou fazer, talvez a pergunta seja reaberta.